# AppBarButtonSyle for WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

Is there a list where I can look for the values for the AppBarButtons?

If I'm looking in the StandardLayout.xaml I found some examples, like this

```
<Style x:Key="ZoomOutButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
  <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="ZoomOutButtonStyle"/>
  <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Zoom Out"/>
  <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE1A4;"/>
</Style>
```

Is there a list for the values like

```
&#xE1A4;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the Character Map program & select the Segoe UI Symbol from the font list:-

[image: Character Map clip]

the bit you are looking for, in your example is, **&#xE1A4** just ignore the **&#x** at the beginning. You can use any font viewer program or check out the free version of  [Syncfusion Metro Studio (2 intro min vid)](http://help.syncfusion.com/metrostudio.htm) at [Syncfusion Metro Studio FREE](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio) for more advanced icon manipulation.

Just have fun trying...

Answer (score 6):

See the complete list of icons (present in StandardLayout.xaml) in Segoe UI Symbol along with their unicode values at http://kishore1021.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/appbar.png. 
Under each icon, you can see the name and unicode values.

To use one of these styles you can simply use the following Xaml in the code.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource RemoveAppBarButtonStyle}"/>
```

Replace the word next to StaticResource with the button you want.

Coming to customizing the button displayed, you can derive your own style from the base style and use setters to set properties with your desired values like in the following code. Here i am displaying a globe icon and the text below the icon is "Get Location".

```
<Style x:Key="GlobeAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" 
BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#x128;" />
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Get Location>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can open the Character Map tool and set the font to Segoe UI Symbol.  The values are from this font.

Comment: But I can't see the items, which a represents by some values, like a glass with a minus or a plus, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following site pretty valuable when trying to work with the Segoe UI Symbols:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx

If I can't find what I want/need there, then I usually use [Metro Studio](http://help.syncfusion.com/metrostudio.htm).